# Search for a file and open the path in CMD

Tags: search, cmd

I would like to achieve the following in CMD:

1. Will search for a specific filename - This I know how to do, with `dir /s filename`
2. Once found it will bring me to that path. 
   Example: I am now on `C:\`, if that file was found in `C:\test` then it will open `C:\test` in command prompt.

Alternatively, I would like just to copy the found file to a path I will specify. I just don't know how to do it, since I don't know the path where the file will be stored (it's different every time).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I managed to make the alternative option to work. By running: `for /R %G IN ("filename.db") DO xcopy "%G" "C:\downloads\Test"`. Problem is when I am putting it in a batch file then I get a syntax error and it runs `for /R G" "C:\downloads\Test"` instead

Comment: I got it! I had to change it to %%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a liitle confused with your question but I will try to walk you through a batch code I wrote to help you with this.

```
dir /b /s "test.txt" > "%userprofile%/Desktop/result.txt"

::find the file path to the file you want to find and insert it in a .txt file
::you made called result.txt (also %userprofile% is a variable that brings you to
::your user directory ex C:/users/admin)

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%userprofile%/desktop/result.txt) do (
    set var1=%%A
)  

::set the variable var1 equal to the first (well... only) line in the file.
::I could explain what that for loop means in detail but just remember that %%A
::is a variable set from what was found when looping through the result.txt.
xcopy /s "%var1%" "C:/wherever/you/want/it/to/go"
```

did this help??